# Date Format Issue on VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, compile-error

I am trying to change the Date Format on VF Page but it is giving me the following error

> The value attribute on  is not in a valid format. It
>   must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice.

Here is my Code

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value=" {!Score.Entry_Date__c}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: What type of field is `Entry_Date__c`?

Comment: @Adrian Larson Date Field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value=" {!Score.Entry_Date__c}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

It looks like you are recieving the error due to the space you have prior to {!Score......

Please try this.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!Score.Entry_Date__c}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it.

Comment: Very bad error reporting, iv seen people spend a lot of time on silly formatting errors that SF do not report clear enough.